# `transform` transition doesn't work in iOS Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-transforms

The transition doesn't work in iOS Chrome, but in iOS Safari works.

Here is an example https://codepen.io/PavelLaptev/pen/gOKGraN

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Text"/>
  <label>Text</label>
</div>
```

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
.test input:focus {
  border: 1px soled red;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
.test input:focus + label {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(-34px) scale(0.6);
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

[image]

*Chrome version 109.0.5414.83*
*iOS 16.2*

Does someone face the same issue?

What could be causing the 'transform' transition to not work in iOS Chrome? Are there any known compatibility issues or potential solutions to fix this issue?

Comment: Seems to be an exisiting issue on chrome ios where css transition doesn't run smoothly - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1249723

Comment: thanks, didn't see that. Hope they'll fix it